# Angular router: named router-outlet

Tags: angular, angular-ui-router

I am trying to implement a named outlet. Basically, it works, but the URL in the address bar would look like this:

```
https://localhost/project/19/(projectEditorRouter:project-details)
```

So, refreshing this URL won't work. It will switch to the default route on the main router. Is it possible after navigating to the named outlet show the final URL like this:

```
https://localhost/project/19/project-details
```

or not to show project-details at all?

Comment: Is this route contained inside of a web component per-chance? Are you using a path location strategy?

Comment: Can you please clarify your question?

Answer (score 1):

as per i understand your question i got one solution hope it's work.

You would define a route with a parameter placeholder in your route configuration, like /project/:id/:details, and then pass the appropriate values when navigating to the named outlet.

```
this.router.navigate(['/project', projectId, 'project-details'], { outlets: { projectEditorRouter: ['project-details'] } });
```

This generate a URL like **https://localhost/project/19/project-details** when navigating to the named outlet.

you can pass the desired URL as a string when navigating to the named outlet.

```
this.$router.push('/project/19/project-details');
```

This would update the URL in the address bar to **https://localhost/project/19/project-details** when navigating to the named outlet.

**`Edit : Example`**

**app.module.ts**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { ProjectComponent } from './project/project.component';
import { ProjectDetailsComponent } from './project-details/project-details.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    ProjectComponent,
    ProjectDetailsComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

**app-routing.module.ts**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { ProjectComponent } from './project/project.component';
import { ProjectDetailsComponent } from './project-details/project-details.component';

const routes: Routes = [
  { path: 'project/:id', component: ProjectComponent, outlet: 'projectEditorRouter' },
  { path: 'project/:id/project-details', component: ProjectDetailsComponent, outlet: 'projectEditorRouter', pathMatch: 'full' },
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

**project.component.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRoute, Router } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-project',
  template: `
    <h1>Project Component</h1>
    <button (click)="navigateToDetails()">Go to Details</button>
  `,
})
export class ProjectComponent {
  projectId: string;

  constructor(private router: Router, private route: ActivatedRoute) {
    this.route.params.subscribe(params => {
      this.projectId = params.id;
    });
  }

  navigateToDetails() {
    this.router.navigate(['/project', this.projectId, { outlets: { projectEditorRouter: ['project-details'] } }]);
  }
}
```

**project-details.component.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-project-details',
  template: `
    <h1>Project Details Component</h1>
  `,
})
export class ProjectDetailsComponent {}
```

With this example, when you click the "Go to Details" button in the ProjectComponent, it will navigate to the ProjectDetailsComponent within the named outlet projectEditorRouter. The URL in the address bar will update to https://localhost/project/19/project-details. Refreshing the page with this URL will correctly load the ProjectDetailsComponent within the named outlet.

Comment: I cannot make it work. Can you please come up with a working example? It still shows "(projectEditorRouter:project-details)" and the end.

Comment: @Mark i've edit my answer can you please check

Comment: @Mark Apologies for the confusion, I've update my code can you please check again.